# Calculating required capacitance for ESC?

Tags: power, capacitor, motor-controller

I'm working on an ESC design, but I'm not sure what capacitance is needed on the output terminals to smoothen out the voltage sags.

Any ideas on how to calculate this?

Comment: You said output terminals. I am assuming you mean input terminals to the ESC. There are no caps on the output of an ESC. 
It's not really about voltage sags with motor drivers. Your motor and circuits won't be damaged by those and your logic won't even know if they are running off a regulator. It's about voltage spikes from interrupting current through the wiring inductance between your battery and ESC blowing up your ESC. Therefore rules of thumb are usually good enough unless you care to figure out your current, transition times, and wiring inductance.

Comment: My rule of thumb has always been “as much as you can afford”. Usually space limitations will kick in before bom cost. You can also start with some and test until you get the right amount.